# How to add/modify new taxonomy terms in node edit form? (taxonomy type is not tag)

Tags: taxonomy-terms

For example, when adding/editing a node, if a needed taxonomy term(category) doesn't exist, then for the user with right permission, he/she can then add a new term without leaving the node editing form? The term should be hierarchical not like tags, for example the category of the content.

I believe I saw a module which can handle this type of thing by providing a button to create new taxo

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for [Taxonomy Other](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_other) module ?

Comment: Doesn't look like Taxonomy Other has a Drupal 7 release. You create the same functionality with the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module though. You can [try out a demonstration here](http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/config-ui).

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Active Tags](https://drupal.org/project/active_tags) for this sort of thing. It has a nice autocomplete function. There will be an option on the Content Type Field form about which behavior it should have when users input a term that doesn't exist (one is to create the term).

Answer (score 1):

add custom link on node form to create taxonomy term and when user create new taxonomy add a destination path of node edit form like www.example.com/taxnomoyterm ?q=node/123/edit

or you can use these modules

[Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs)

[Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)